# Regex for char array MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, expression

I have char array 4x5 called fur with this content

```
 Name        Size     Bytes  Class    Attributes

  func        4x5     448     char
```

I wanted to look for a specific expression,

```
DG= regexpi(fur,expression);
```

when I use the function regexpi alone I get the error :
The 'STRING' input must be a row vector of char or cell array of strings.

```
DG = cellfun(@(x)regexp(x, expression), fur,'UniformOutput', false)
```

I tried to do it with cellfun, but I still get an error:
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was char instead.

Any solution? Thank you very much

Comment: Surely there should be a comma behind `fur`.

Comment: Yeah was a typing mistake, but this is not the error

Comment: You can also use: `regexp(fur(:)',expr)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cellfun, your data should be cell oriented.

Currently you have an nxm char array.

To use cellfun one would want for instance n cells with an 1xm char array in each cell.

I am not sure whether there is an easy and more efficient solution, but a quick fix would be to create the required cell array by using cellstr on your chararray.

Note that in that case you would not need cellfun anymore as you could do the rexexp directly.

Comment: `cellstr` will convert a string in that format to a cell array of strings (rowwise) and since `regexpi` works on cell arrays you should be able to use it without `cellfun`